# Filter function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on an e-commerce site and I'm stuck on the search page, especially when filtering the products.
**
This is the HTML code for the product card:**

```
<div class="product-seller-item" data-brand="Louis Vuitton" data-category="Helmets">
            <div class="product-page-seller-item-header">
              <img src="/Images/user.png" alt="User profile image">
              <p>citygirl1996</p>
            </div>
            <img class="product-page-seller-item-body-image" src="/Images/Products/product1.png" alt="">
            <div class="product-page-seller-item-footer">
              <div class="product-page-seller-item-footer-flex">
                <p>£15.00</p>
              </div>
              <p class="product-page-seller-item-footer-description">Juicy Couture</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And this is the code for the checkbox:

```
 <label class="container">Helmets
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Helmets">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                      </label>

<label class="container">Louis Vuitton
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Louis Vuitton">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                      </label>
```

And this is the code for JavaScript:

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
const products = document.querySelectorAll('.product-seller-item');

for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
    for (let j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
      let productVisible = false;
      for (let k = 0; k < checkboxes.length; k++) {
        if (checkboxes[k].checked && products[j].dataset.category === checkboxes[k].value) {
          productVisible = true;
          break;
        } else if (checkboxes[k].checked && products[j].dataset.brand
          && products[j].dataset.brand === checkboxes[k].parentElement.textContent.trim()) {
          productVisible = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (productVisible) {
        products[j].style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        products[j].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is as follows, when I select the Helmets category, it shows me all of them, everything works perfectly, but when I select the brand, it doesn't hide the product that doesn't match.

Comment: Is the products coming from a database or are they hardcoded?

Comment: For the moment, they are hardcoded, they are just to test the functionality, later a database will be implemented by a developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the products have a category you can use `filter`method, that will return you a new array with the elements that have this conditions. For example:

```
const products = document.querySelectorAll('.products'):
const categories = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
const filteredProducts 
= products.filter(product => product.category == categories.checked);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'm pretty new to JS, can you help me implement this in my code?

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now. Check this sandbox where is an example it can helps you :)

https://codepen.io/piotrek/pen/mXpRmQ